# Retrofit 1.9 raw response cannot be processed in success callback

Tags: android, gson, proguard, retrofit

My first understanding was that ProGuard caused that the response object could not be retrieved in the Retrofit success callback. However the problem is that Retrofit returns the raw response object (second argument) in the success callback depending on the log level.

See my own answer below.

IOException reported by Google:

> com.google.a.ae: java.io.IOException: closed  at
>   com.google.a.k.a(Unknown Source)  at com.google.a.k.a(Unknown Source)
>     at com.myapp.rest.model.ApiResponse.parseResponse(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.myapp.service.e.a(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.myapp.service.e.success(Unknown Source)   at
>   retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: closed    at c.x.read(Unknown Source)
>     at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:231)   at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.fillBuf(BufferedReader.java:145)   at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:333)  at
>   com.google.a.d.a.b(Unknown Source)    at com.google.a.d.a.b(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.google.a.d.a.A(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.google.a.d.a.o(Unknown Source)    at com.google.a.d.a.f(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 14 more

Asynchronous retrofit request:

```
@POST("/api/myobjects")
void newMyObject(@Body MyObject myObject, Callback<MyObject> cb);
```

The Retrofit success callback:

```
public void success(MyObject myObject, Response raw) {
    try { 
        ApiResponse res = ApiResponse.parseResponse(raw);
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        super.failure(RetrofitError.unexpectedError(raw.getUrl(), e));
    }
}
```

And parsing the API response:

```
public static ApiResponse parseResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getBody().in()));
    return gson.fromJson(reader, ApiResponse.class);
}
```

Implemented ProGuard following Retrofit and Gson guidelines:

```
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn jce.**
-dontwarn javax.naming.**

# keep okhttp & retrofit following retrofit guidelines
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }

-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>; }

# keep gson following google guidelines
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# keep application classes that are serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.myapp.rest.model.** { *; }

# keep the data for stacktraces
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes LineNumberTable
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

Some further analysis shows that the response is available, 
but the connection is already closed when parsing the response object.
Below log shows that the response URL and status can be retrieved
in the Retrofit success callback.

> 12-17 10:39:46.639 4192-4192/? I/com.myapp.service.e:
>   https://urlto/api/myobjects?locale=en&app=xxx 12-17 10:39:46.639
>   4192-4192/? I/com.myapp.service.e: OK  12-17 10:39:46.649
>   4192-4192/?W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught
>   exception (group=0x4208f8e0)  12-17 10:39:46.669 4192-4192/?
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main com.google.gson.ae:
>   java.io.IOException: closed at com.google.gson.k.a(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research it shows that it is a known feature for Retrofit to not return the raw response body (Inputstream is read and closed), when log level is not FULL.

See: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/953 (Closed). Not clear to me why it is closed, as second argument behaves unexpected differently depending on the log level.

Workaround suggested by others is to return the Response object in the first argument. Alternative is to keep the log level on FULL.